# how to trigger all anchor tags on click of a button?

Tags: jquery, html

sorry if title is wrong

i want to open all the links on a single click

thank you in advance

```js
$(function(){
  $("#bb").click(function(){
    $('a').click();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div>
    <a href="1.link">test</a>
    <br />
    <a href="2.link">test2</a>
    <br>
    <input type="button" id="bb" value="click">
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: what is happening when you run your code?

Comment: its open only last link @guradio

Comment: Your current code should be doing what you require. If it isn't, check the console for errors. Although it should be said, what exactly are you expecting to happen when you click N `a` elements all at the same time?

Comment: give anchors `target = "_blank"` attribute.

Comment: [check demo](https://jsfiddle.net/jowL5dtk/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try like following.

```
$("#bb").click(function () {
    $('a').each(function() {
        window.open($(this).attr('href'), '_blank');
    });
});
```